# How to use Sass in Django and versioning CSS and JS assets for cache busting

Tags: javascript, css, django, laravel, gulp

So I started a project in Laravel/MySQL and it became apparent after talking to some more experienced developers that Django/PostgreSQL might have been a better choice for the app.

Despite being a Django newb, I have been converting it over Django and there is one feature in Laravel that I am not seeing in Django that I was wondering how to implement. In Laravel it is a combination of `Gulp` and `Elixir` that manages Sass to CSS compiling and also versioning CSS and JS files.

In `gulpfile.js` for Laravel the code is this:

```
elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('styles.scss')
       .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js', 'css/styles.css', 'js/custom.js']);
});
```

It is then read into the Blade template with:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/styles.css') }}">    

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ elixir('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

I am not seeing a similar functionality in Django so was wondering how to implement it because it is very handy turning `watch` on then having assets Sass->CSS and JS compiled, and versioned.

I do see various `npm` packages out there: `gulp`, `gulp-django`, `django-sass`, etc. And then I see other packages like `gulp-buster` or `gulp-cache-bust`. It isn't clear to me if `gulp` comes with these packages, if they needed to be downloaded in addition to `gulp`, or I just need a `django` specific `gulp`.

Figured someone here would know how to add similar functionality to the `Gulp`/`Elixir` combo in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [django_assets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-assets) for this.  For my CSS and SASS files, I use an `assets.py` file that looks like this:

```
css_bundle = Bundle(
    'scss/main.scss',
    depends=('scss/**/*.scss',),
    filters='pyscss,cssmin',
    output='compiled/main.min.css'
)

register('css_bundle', css_bundle)
```

Which I can then include in my templates like this:

```
{% assets "css_bundle" %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}"/>
{% endassets %}
```

Cache busting is built right in, and you can do something similar for JS files.